# code not showing result on online compiler

Tags: c++, debugging, ide

I was trying to write code for vertical order traversal of a tree and my code prints the result on code::blocks however it is not printing the result when the same thing is run in the geekforgeeks online ide. Why is it doing this?

```
void getvert(Node* root,int hd,map<int,vector<int>>m){
    if(root==NULL)return;
    m[hd].push_back(root->data);
    getvert(root->left,hd-1,m);
    getvert(root->right,hd+1,m);
}



void verticalOrder(Node *root)
{
    map<int,vector<int>>m;
    int hd=0;
    getvert(root,hd,m);

    auto it=m.begin();
   for(;it!=m.end();it++)
   {
        for (int i=0; i<it->second.size(); ++i)
            cout<<it->second[i];
        cout<<endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `getvert` accepts the last argument, `m`, as a value. Changes made to it in the function are made to a local copy of the object. Hence, you don't see any changes in `verticalOrder`.

Change `getvert` so that it accepts `m` as a reference.

```
void getvert(Node* root,int hd, map<int,vector<int>>& m) // Need reference argument
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: @mariumali -- Bottom line, C++ is not Java.